# set color of jbuttons by using a for loop instead of making a hundred .setForeground(Color.red);

Tags: swing, loops, colors, for-loop, jbutton

I have a hundred buttons called

JButton btnHelp1, btnHelp2, ... btnHelp100;

I want to go from string to a jbutton name for another method to set the foreground like so

```
    for(x = 1; x < 101; x++){ 
        String buttonName = "btnHelp" + x;
        // convert by doing something like...
        JButton a = buttonName;
        a.setForeground(Color.yellow);
    }
```

Comment: You can use a class for that if i understand question correctly.

Comment: is there a class to convert a string to jbutton name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are describing isn't possible. However, you can add all of your buttons in a `List`, and go through every elements (buttons) of your list and change its background.

```
for (JButton button: myButtonsList) {
    button.setBackground (Color.Yellow)
}
```

Comment: You sir, are the greatest artist who ever lived!

Comment: +1 for `List`, but not all L&Fs display a button's background.

Answer (score 2):

Did you create the `JButtons`? Instead of naming all of them, **keep the JButton references in an array or list:**

```
JButton[] buttons = new JButton[100];

for (int i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    buttons[i] = new JButton();
    // other commonalities
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another perhaps easier solution is to create a subclass of `JButton` called `HelpButton` and in the constructor you can set the foreground color along with other properties. Then all you need to change is your construction of the buttons to instantiate a help button, like:

```
JButton btnHelp = new HelpButton();
```